# windows phone 8.1 bing maps clustering

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bing-maps

Hello i am using windows map control described in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207033(v=vs.105).aspx) link and i have a MapLayer with multiple MapOverlays with differents pois on map. And i want to do the clustering thing. I try to do [this](https://mapstoolbox.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Bing%20Maps%20Clustering%20Functionality) but no ClusteringLayer exist and no Pushpin. How can i do the clustering?

```
var cluster = new ClusteringLayer();

layer = new ClusteringLayer(Mymap)
        {
            ClusterRadius = 10,
            ClusterType = ClusteringType.Grid
        };

//Add event handlers to create the pushpins 
layer.CreateClusteredItemPushpin += CreateClusteredItemPushpin1;
layer.CreateItemPushpin+=layer_CreateItemPushpin;

    private MapOverlay layer_CreateItemPushpin(object item, ClusteredPoint clusterInfo)
    {
        var x = clusterInfo.Location;
        var poi = new BuildingPoi { Coordinate = x, Buid = _selectedBuild };
        var imagePoiLocation = new Image
        {
            Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/MapPin.png", UriKind.Relative)),
            DataContext = poi
        };

        var over = new MapOverlay();

        imagePoiLocation.Tap += loadClickedBuilding;
        over.Content = imagePoiLocation;
        over.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
        over.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(x.Latitude, x.Longitude);

        return over;
    }

    private MapOverlay CreateClusteredItemPushpin1(ClusteredPoint clusterInfo)
    {
        var x = clusterInfo.Location;
        var poi = new BuildingPoi { Coordinate = x, Buid = _selectedBuild };
        var imagePoiLocation = new Image
        {
            Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/MapPin.png", UriKind.Relative)),
            DataContext = poi
        };

        var over = new MapOverlay();

        imagePoiLocation.Tap += loadClickedBuilding;
        over.Content = imagePoiLocation;
        over.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
        over.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(x.Latitude, x.Longitude);

        return over;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As they don't have any nuget package or dll to reference directly, you need to download the [source code](https://mapstoolbox.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) of specific classes like `ClusteringLayer` & `PushPin` with related .cs files or the project itself to your machine and add reference of this project in your windows phone project to get `ClusteringLayer` and `PushPin` classes.

See following screenshot for `ClusteringLayer` class. For other classes, just import the solution to visual studio and you will see source code of all the classes. BTW, `ClusteringLayer` constructor need at-least one argument in cluster.

I advice you to download source code and get familiar with it's usage from samples in source code.

[image]

Comment: where is the source code of this classes i cant find it. i have download the solution and wp8.1 samples not working. it says that the project is incompatible with the current version of vs

Comment: i will check it now and i will tell you if that works

Comment: hello again i cant add the project as reference. i have add the classes to my project but it needs more classes

Comment: So, just add them. Where are you stuck? :)

Comment: Try running there sample and see if you see anything. If you don't see anything then probably you might not be connected to internet, hence nothing on map.

Comment: i cant see the windows phone 8.1 sample because it sais that the project is incompatible with the current version of vs

Comment: Then you will have to update your VS. I've ran there sample and it works for me. :)

Comment: i run it but what i see is some red and blue dots that are above the map and nothing happens when zoom in or out

Comment: Red and blue dots shots pushpin. You will have to to add zoom events